# Using SUM in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am a new Laravel learner and having difficulty to convert from sql

here is my sql

```
select sum(employee_income) 
from employee 
group by employee_id, employee_department
```

this query works when I test.

here is my simplified Laravel but it doesn't work.

```
DB::raw('(select sum(employee_income) from employee group by employee_id, employee_department)')
```

Can anybody see something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `DB::raw()` unless you have to. Laravel has the Eloquent Query Builder, which provides an easy to type, Database-agnostic (works with all DBs) method of writing queries. This one should be pretty simple:

```
$sum = Employee::groupBy('employee_id')
->groupBy('employee_department')
->sum('employee_income');

// Or, if you don't have an `Employee.php` model

$sum = DB::table('employees')
->groupBy('employee_id')
->groupBy('employee_department')
->sum('employee_income');
```